# How to fix [HTTP 403] Unable to create record in twilio?

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I'm trying to implement fax sending and receiving using laravel. But unfortunately, I'm getting this error. Please see the error and my code below.

**Error**

> Twilio\Exceptions\RestException 
> [HTTP 403] Unable to create record: '+15005550006' is not a valid destination for trial accounts

**Code**

```
public function send()
{
    $sid    = env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID');
    $token  = env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
    $to = env('TO_EXAMPLE');
    $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
    $mediaURL = asset('pdfs/dummy.pdf');
    $from = ["from" => '+' . env('TWILIO_NUMBER')];

    $fax = $twilio->fax->v1->faxes
        ->create('+' . $to, $mediaURL, $from);

    print($fax->sid);
}
```

**Reference**

https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Do not use your TEST credentials. Use your LIVE credentials. +15005550006 is reserved for use with TEST credentials.

[How To Use Twilio Test Credentials with Magic Phone Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/04/twilio-test-credentials-magic-numbers.html)